# Match vim help tags with regex

Tags: python, regex, vim

So I want to write a regex to search for tags in vim help files using grep. Tags are defined like `*some-tag*`. So far I have tried these on this [file](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/options.txt)

`\\*(.*?)\\*` - Matches tags but also matches `*.o,*` in `:set wildignore=*.o,*.obj` and also matches `*" (e.g., "10*50...`

Maybe the tags should have spaces after and before. So I tried `\s\\*(.*?)\\*\s` but it matches alternate tags when they are written consecutively, because the first match consumes the ending space.

So I used lookahead `(?<=\s)\\*(.*?)\\*(?=\s)`. This works, but it doesn't match the tags at the start of the file.

What should be the proper way to write the regex?

Comment: Try: `r'(?:^|\s)\*(.*?)\*(?=\s)'` which will conditionally match either the start of the string, or preceding whitespace.

Comment: PS I have a similar one [here](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/vim/autoload/help.vim) for « clickable » items in `:help`